# Template receiving container as argument

Tags: c++, templates

I'm doing a template, which represents container with filter. It will contain all methods that container should have, but all methods will work with that filter. So e.g. if the filter is `>1` then `begin()` will return first element suitable that filter. I'd like to ask if that template declaration is correct, or what should it look like? Should it be template in template or ?

```
template<typename Container,class Filter>
class filtered_cont{
//methods working with container
}
```

Comment: This may be a job for inheritance filtered_cont deriving from container. It can still be a template in Filter, this way goes the concept way, only stuff expecting a filtered_cont can work with this, so there's no way to enforce that it be a container (other than compile time errors that in no way suggest this (assuming you don't put a static assert and check for the presence of every method)))

Comment: Looks OK. You can handle the filter similarly to how allocators are handled in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you are changing is the iterators returned by begin() and end(), I wouldn't mess with the containers ... leave them be, just create helper functions that take containers and filters and return your new iterator:

```
template<typename Container, typename Predicate>
magic_it filter_begin(Container aContainer, Predicate p) { /.../  return magic ; }
```